# Would 'type: Undefined' default to AnyObject?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9

In the image below, if I don't assign the attribute a type, what type will it have by default?

[image]

Comment: Did you try it? Does it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation:

> NSUndefinedAttributeType is valid for transient properties—Core Data will still track the property as an id value and register undo/redo actions, and so on. NSUndefinedAttributeType is illegal for non-transient properties.

Type Undefined is used for non-standard type properties. When Xcode creates a NSManagedObject subclass, the type is UNKNOWN_TYPE.